# "is not null here"

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, c#-4.0, null

I have a method that continuously gives me a warning "is not null here".

```
        StockHolding stockHoldingFiltered = new StockHolding();
        List<StockHolding> stockHoldingsFiltered = new List<StockHolding>();
        IReadOnlyList<StockHolding> stockHoldings = this.GetAll();

        stockHoldingsFiltered = stockHoldings.Where(stckhold =>
            stckhold.PortfolioId.Equals(portfolioId) &&
            stckhold.StockSymbol.Equals(stockSymbol)).ToList();

        if(stockHoldingsFiltered != null)
            stockHoldingFiltered = stockHoldingsFiltered.FirstOrDefault();

        return stockHoldingFiltered;
```

Warning: 'stockHoldingFiltered' is not null here.
CS8600: Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.

I cannot get this warning to go away. Has anyone run into this and were able to resolve this warning?

Answer (score 6):

This issue is with your if statement. You are doing a null check on a `ToList()`. The list isn't going to be null, but it can however be empty. Here is your code below to demonstrate this.

```
void Main()
{
    int portfolioId = 1;
    string stockSymbol = "USD";

    StockHolding stockHoldingFiltered = new StockHolding();
    List<StockHolding> stockHoldingsFiltered = new List<StockHolding>();
    IReadOnlyList<StockHolding> stockHoldings = StockHolding.GetAll();

    stockHoldingsFiltered = stockHoldings.Where(stckhold =>
        stckhold.PortfolioId.Equals(portfolioId) &&
        stckhold.StockSymbol.Equals(stockSymbol)).ToList();

    if (stockHoldingsFiltered != null) // this cannot be null as its returning a list. It might be empty but not null.
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I WASN't NULL, but has no records. Line below will fail.");
        //stockHoldingFiltered = stockHoldingsFiltered.FirstOrDefault();
    }
    
    if(stockHoldingsFiltered.Count > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I wasnt null but had 0 records. Line below is safe");
        stockHoldingFiltered = stockHoldingsFiltered.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    //return stockHoldingFiltered;
}

// You can define other methods, fields, classes and namespaces here
public class StockHolding
{
    public int PortfolioId { get; set; }
    public string StockSymbol { get; set; }
    
    public static IReadOnlyList<StockHolding> GetAll()
    {
        List<StockHolding> someList = new List<StockHolding>();
        
        return someList;
        
    }
}
```

This outputs: `I WASN't NULL, but has no records. Line below will fail.`

So instead of `if (stockHoldingsFiltered != null)` try using `if(stockHoldingsFiltered.Count > 0)`

That warning will go away.

Comment: Exactly correct. Its warning against the null check against something that isn't actually null. Change the null to a `.Count` and it'll go away.

Comment: I made the specified edit, but the warning still shows.

Comment: update your code to reflect your changes.